# Runtime path for DllImport Attribute on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I'm looking for a solution for dynamically change the dll path when using DLLImport attribute under Linux. I have an if statement for checking the current OS (`RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)`), and if the application runs on windows than I'm using the `SetDllDirectory` method from `kernel32.dll` to dynamically add a folder to the dll search path.

For Windows I have two different dlls to load based on some runtime decision. they will be located at `Environment.CurrentDirectory + Drivers/Win/1/` and `Environment.CurrentDirectory + Drivers/Win/2/`.

For Linux, the `.so` will be located at `Environment.CurrentDirectory + Drivers/Linux/`

The `dlls` and `so` files have the exact same interface and name.

Is there an equivalent solution like `SetDllDirectory` for Linux under .NET 5?

Thanks

Comment: Use NativeLibrary: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/09/06/interacting-with-native-libraries-in-net-core-3-0